# How to stop Spotify from starting with Windows

Tags: windows-10, spotify

Spotify for Windows (not from app store) starts itself whenever I boot up Windows. I have turned off the setting to open Spotify automatically after logging in:

[image: spotify settings]

I have also checked the Windows Start Settings. Spotify is not listed as a program that will run during startup:

[image: windows start settings]

Where else should I check? Is it possible to make Spotify not run during boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @John for suggesting Sysinternals' Autoruns. It was a great utility app. However Spotify was not listed in the Logon tab or in any other Autoruns tabs.

It turned out that I have activated 'Restart apps' in 'Sign-in options' in 'Accounts' in Windows Settings:

[image: windows settings accounts sign in options restart apps]

So it was my own mistake.

Answer (score 2):

> Spotify for Windows (not from app store) starts itself whenever I boot
> up Windows.  Where else should I check? Is it possible to make Spotify
> not run during boot?

Open Task Manager, Startup Tab and look there for Spotify. If there, you can uncheck and stop it from starting. I use this feature.

[image: Task Manager]

.

It is is not there, get Autoruns (SysInternals) and check it for Spotify. You can uncheck it here as well.

[image: Autoruns]

Either or both of these tools should show you.

Restart to test.

If you run into issues, uninstall Spotify, restart, make sure all is working properly and then try installing it again.